# how to play sound using java

Tags: java, javasound

I am trying to play a sound(a.mp3 ) on button ckick in java.

I tried this code

> AudioPlayer.player.start(new FileInputStream(new File("E://a.mp3")));

but the sound is not clear....

What should I do,(I'm a beginner in java).

Comment: What is the `AudioPlayer` class? This isn't part of the J2SE API.

Answer (score 1):

```
   **For Playing sound in java, please refer to the following code.**

 import java.io.*;
    import java.net.URL;
    import javax.sound.sampled.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    // To play sound using Clip, the process need to be alive.
    // Hence, we use a Swing application.
    public class SoundClipTest extends JFrame {

       // Constructor
       public SoundClipTest() {
          this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          this.setTitle("Test Sound Clip");
          this.setSize(300, 200);
          this.setVisible(true);

          try {
             // Open an audio input stream.
             URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("filenamme.mp3");
             AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
             // Get a sound clip resource.
             Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
             // Open audio clip and load samples from the audio input stream.
             clip.open(audioIn);
             clip.start();
          } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
          new SoundClipTest();
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at this article.
http://www.morgenstille.at/blog/how-to-play-a-mp3-file-in-java-simple-and-beautiful/

Also [JFugue](http://www.jfugue.org/index.html) can load and play midi files.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [JLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html). It's the best library I could find a couple of years ago. It's not perfect, but should fit your needs.